# Why won't C# inline functions with struct parameters?

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, inline

At http://blogs.msdn.com/ericgu/archive/2004/01/29/64717.aspx, we learn that C# will not inline methods with structs as formal parameters.  Is this due to potential dependence on the stack, e.g. for recursion?  If so, could I potentially benefit by turning struct parameters into ref parameters like this?

```
public int Sum(int i)
{
  return array1[i] + array2[i];
}
```

turns into:

```
public int Sum(ref int i)
{
  return array1[i] + array2[i];
}
```

Edit:  I went to attempt a test, but I can't get anything in inline.  Here is what I tried:

```
class Program
{
  private static string result;
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
    Console.WriteLine();
    m1();
    Console.WriteLine(result);
  }
  private static void m1()
  {
    result = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
  }
}
```

It prints "m1" as the second line, which indicates that it did not get inlined.  I built a Release build and ran it with Ctrl-F5 (to not attach the debugger).  Any ideas?

Comment: Note that that blog post was from nearly five and a half years ago. Things may have changed since then...

Comment: It's not a reliable way to see a method would be inlined or not as you are changing the method.

Comment: That's probably not the best way to determine whether or not inlining is occuring.  Take a look at this article for some guidance:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/JITOptimizations.aspx

Comment: inlining the above method would alter the program the result of execusion. I hope no compilers try and guess what the programmer ment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Jon said, it's a very old post. I can confirm that in the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

struct MyStruct
{
   public MyStruct(int p)
   {
      X = p;
   }
   public int X;

   // prevents optimization of the whole thing to a constant.
   [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
   static int GetSomeNumber()
   {
       return new Random().Next();
   }

   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      MyStruct x = new MyStruct(GetSomeNumber());
      // the following line is to prevent further optimization:
      for (int i = inlinetest(x); i != 100 ; i /= 2) ; 
   }

   static int inlinetest(MyStruct x)
   {
      return x.X + 1;
   }
}
```

`inlinetest` method is inlined.

Main method disassembly:

```
; set up the stack frame:
00000000  push        ebp
00000001  mov         ebp,esp 

; calls GetSomeNumber:
00000003  call        dword ptr ds:[005132D8h] 

; inlined function:
00000009  inc         eax  

; the dummy for loop:
0000000a  cmp         eax,64h 
0000000d  je          0000001B 
0000000f  sar         eax,1 
00000011  jns         00000016 
00000013  adc         eax,0 
00000016  cmp         eax,64h 
00000019  jne         0000000F 
0000001b  pop         ebp  
0000001c  ret
```

I've tested this on x86 .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 on Windows 7 x64 RC.

As I believed there's nothing inherently wrong with inlining methods with `struct` parameters. Probably, JIT has not been smart enough at that time.

Comment: I discovered the ['Inlining Analyzer' Extension for Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=StephanZehetner.InliningAnalyzer) or [GitHub](https://github.com/szehetner/InliningAnalyzer) which makes this analysis a bit easier for the specific cases. It can also tell you why something is not inlined.  It also confirms your answer above.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/vancem/archive/2008/08/19/to-inline-or-not-to-inline-that-is-the-question.aspx)'s a better article describing why some methods will not be inlined.  And [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=93858) is a MS connect feedback entry with comments that include benchmark results (FWIW)

Answer (score 0):

A bit of clarification.  That blog is not discussing what C# will or won't inline.  It is discussing what the JITer will or won't inline.

As to why the JITer does not inline methods with structs as formal parameters, I do not know.
However I am relatively certain that if they won't inline a method with a struct parameter, then making the struct by ref won't change that decision.

Comment: @JaredPar: I'm not sure about what I'm going to say... but I think `struct` here has a narrow meaning. Primitive types such as `int` are treated differently by the runtime. Ain't it?

Comment: @Mehrdad for the JITer, I'm unsure as to how it will treat a normal struct vs. a primitive.  My guess is it will inline certain operations on primitives more aggresively but I can't find any documentation to back that up at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is because this would involve changing the size of the stack frame created for that method.  With a reference type, (a class) the stack frame has to allow for the storage of a pointer (to the object on the Heap) whereas with a struct ALL the structs primitive fields must be added to the stackframes footprint.

Answer (score -3):

This is a **value-type versus reference-type issue**, as you noted. Imagine that you have a function that has a value-type (say, int) argument, and you **change that variable in the function**. Obviously, this has **no side effects in the calling function**, as you passed by value and not by reference.

Now imagine that you inline the same code. All of a sudden, **your variable is changing in the calling function**! Not what you intended.

You can probably convince yourself by thinking through the same scenario with a reference type that **inlining has no problems for by-ref params** - a change in the original function has the same repurcussions as a change in an inlined version of that function.

That's WHY it doesn't allow it, but I agree that there should be some way for you to tell the compiler that you "guarantee" that your function has no side effects on value-type arguments. Might be nice for performance reasons in a lot of cases.

Incidentally, you can always declare a module level int and bypass the argument all together :) Much uglier, but you would end up inlining the function in question.

Whatever you decide to do, good luck!

EDIT: I just remembered that there was an ancient C compiler on Irix (the SGI operating system) that actually had a compiler option for this, allowing you to "force" inlining. So it can be done, but I agree with the choice made here, opting for the less error-prone default.

Comment: I disagree that stack or making a side effect is the reason. I think that's mostly because of parameter size variance issues that make it hard to inline those stuff. It's completely possible to set a reference type inside a method to another value: `void x(string s) { s = "hello"; }` That's not much different from a struct version.

Comment: I disagree as well, see the links in my post for a less speculative view.